# Passing variables between kernels in OpenCL 1.2 / Communication between kernels

Tags: c++, kernel, opencl, global, communication

I am relatively new to OpenCL. I am using the OpenCL 1.2 C++ wrapper. Say I have the following problem: I have three integer values a, b, and c all declared on the host

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int help;
int d;
```

with d being my result and help being a help variable.

I want to calculate d = (a + b)*c. To do this, I now have two kernels called 'add' and 'multiply'.

Currently, I am doing this the following way (please don't be confused by my pointer oriented way of programming): First, I create my buffers

```
bufferA = new cl::Buffer(*context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, buffer_length);
cl::Buffer bufferB = new cl::Buffer(*context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, buffer_length);
bufferC = new cl::Buffer(*context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, buffer_length);
bufferHelp = new cl::Buffer(*context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, buffer_length);
bufferD = new cl::Buffer(*context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, buffer_length);
```

Then, I set my kernel arguments for the addition kernel

```
add->setArg(0, *bufferA);
add->setArg(1, *bufferB);
add->setArg(2, *bufferHelp);
```

and for the multiplicatoin kernel

```
multiply->setArg(0, *bufferC);
multiply->setArg(1, *bufferHelp);
multiply->setArg(2, *bufferD);
```

Then I enqueue my data for the addition

```
queueAdd->enqueueWriteBuffer(*bufferA, CL_TRUE, 0, datasize, &a);
queueAdd->enqueueWriteBuffer(*bufferB, CL_TRUE, 0, datasize, &b);
queueAdd->enqueueNDRangeKernel(*add, cl::NullRange, global[0], local[0]);
queueAdd->enqueueReadBuffer(*bufferHelp, CL_TRUE, 0, datasize, &help);
```

and for the multiplication

```
queueMult->enqueueWriteBuffer(*bufferC, CL_TRUE, 0, datasize, &c);
queueMult->enqueueWriteBuffer(*bufferHelp, CL_TRUE, 0, datasize, &help);
queueMult->enqueueNDRangeKernel(*multiply, cl::NullRange, global[0], local[0]);
queueMult->enqueueReadBuffer(*bufferD, CL_TRUE, 0, datasize, &d);
```

This works in a fine way. However, I do not want to copy the value of help back to the host and then back on the device again. To achieve this, I thought of 3 possiblities:

1. a global variable for help on the device side. Doing this, both kernels could access the value of help at any time.
2. kernel add calling kernel multiply at runtime. We then would insert the value for c into the add kernel and pass both help and c over to the multiply kernel as soon as the addition has finished.
3. Simply pass the value of help over to the multiplication kernel. What I search here is something like a pipe object as available for OpenCL 2.0. Does anybody know something similar for OpenCL 1.2.?

I would be very thankful if somebody could propose the smoothest way to solve my problem!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to read and write the `bufferHelp`. Just leave it in device memory. The number `1)` of your proposed solution is how `cl::Buffers` already are, globals in device memory.

This is equivalent to your code and will produce same results:

```
queueAdd->enqueueWriteBuffer(*bufferA, CL_FALSE, 0, datasize, &a);
queueAdd->enqueueWriteBuffer(*bufferB, CL_FALSE, 0, datasize, &b);
queueAdd->enqueueNDRangeKernel(*add, cl::NullRange, global[0], local[0]);
//queueAdd->enqueueReadBuffer(*bufferHelp, CL_FALSE, 0, datasize, &help);

queueMult->enqueueWriteBuffer(*bufferC, CL_FALSE, 0, datasize, &c);
//queueMult->enqueueWriteBuffer(*bufferHelp, CL_FALSE, 0, datasize, &help);
queueMult->enqueueNDRangeKernel(*multiply, cl::NullRange, global[0], local[0]);
queueMult->enqueueReadBuffer(*bufferD, CL_TRUE, 0, datasize, &d);
```

*NOTE: I also changed the blocking write calls, this will provide much better speed, because copy of buffer C and execution of kernel "add" can be parallelized.*

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it works that simple, thanks a lot!!!

Just for other readers: I added queueAdd->finish(); at the end of the first block in the above answer to ensure that the first kernel has finished.